# managing asynchronous curl requests in php

Tags: php, curl

I found a way to perform non-blocking executions using curl like so

```
public function callUrl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 200);

    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

This works great and is non blocking. My only issue with this is how do I manage these calls, how would I forcibly kill one of these background curl requests if they run for too long? I'm looking for a solution that works on both windows and linux.

Comment: I can't see where this should be non blocking

Comment: How about use curl_multi?

Comment: hek2mgl, it's non blocking beleive me I'm using it. The URL it's calling is actually pointing back to another php route on the server which executes the long blocking task. The code I'm showing above is the API with my front end which allows to send the request to start the job but respond instantly before the task is finished.    Macattack: I was not aware of it thank you I will check it out.

Comment: >>  how do I manage these calls?<br>Perhaps by implementing two callback functions, one for upload (see CURLOPT_READFUNCTION) and one for download (see CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION). So while your process is reading/writting bytes via callbacks (instead of the default Curl mechanism) all you have to do (inside these callback functions) is to listen if some state parameter/function has changed. If yes then you can abort the data transmission/recival as per Curl documentation (see the documentation for these 2 functions).